# A question about a theorem concerning Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

The theorem stats that

> Every sequence n^2 + 1 distinct real numbers contains a subsequence of length n+1 that is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

However, I came up with "counterexample", a sequence of numbers -- 5 6 4 7 3 8 2 9 1 10.
It is a sequence of length (3^2 + 1) but there is not subsequence qualifying the theorem.

Comment: What about 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10? The numbers in the subsequence don't have to be adjacent.

Comment: In addition, there are only nine numbers in that sequence. Unless you mean $1\,0$ instead of $10.$

Comment: There are *several* subsequences satisfying the theorem.  ($5,6,7,8$), ($5,6,7,9$), ($5,7,8,10$), ($5,6,8,9$), $(5,6,8,10)$, ($5,6,9,10$), ($5,7,8,9$),($5,7,8,10$),($5,7,9,10$),($5,8,9,10)$, ($6,7,8,9$), ($6,7,8,10$), $(6,8,9,10)$, $(7,8,9,10)$ $(5,4,3,2)$, $(6,4,3,2)$ are $16$ sub sequences that qualify.  That's actually a *lot*.

Comment: Essentially, you are confusing a sub-string with a sub-sequence. A substring of length $4$ is any four in a row. A sub-sequence is any four from the sequence, presented in order. If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ a sub-string of length $m$ is of the form $a_i,a_{i +1},\cdots, a_{i +m-1},$ with $1\leq i \leq n-m.$ A sub-sequence is of the form $a_{i_1}, a_{i_2},\dots, a_{i_m}$ with $1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots <i_m\leq n.$

Comment: Thanks for these answers. I think I indeed was confused with the subsequence concept. Yes, numbers in a sequence doesn't have to be adjacent to constitute a subsequence.

Comment: Another question is that what could be considered "loosely increasing or loosely decreasing" with respect to "strictly increasing or strictly decreasing"?

Answer (score 1):

Not only do sequence members not need to be adjacent to qualify as a subsequence , but, strictly increasing or strictly decreasing mean $a>b$, $a$ being a number further up on the number line, and in the sequence, and $b<a$, $b$ being a number further down (as in towards the negative end) of the number line, respectively. Loosely (technically weakly), means they could be equal in value as well.